# Postgresql Need a query that gives me all the parents that don't have child with a specific status value

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, exists

This is the parent table named `route`

| id | start_day | end_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |
| 2 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |
| 3 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |
| 4 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |
| 5 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |

Child table named `route_detail`

| id | route_id | visit_status | point_of_delivery_plant_name | point_of_delivery_plant_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | CROP SOLUTIONS S.A. | 563 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | CROP SOLUTIONS S.A. | 563 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | CROP SOLUTIONS S.A. | 563 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | SAMA S.A. | 781 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | WALTER SAMA HARMS | 732 |
| 6 | 4 | 5 | AGROSER S.A. | 242 |
| 7 | 4 | 5 | AGROSER S.A. | 242 |
| 8 | 5 | 5 | AGROFERTIL S.A | 287 |
| 9 | 5 | 5 | AGROFERTIL S.A | 287 |
| 10 | 5 | 5 | AGROFERTIL S.A | 287 |

and a third child table named `event`, for each record `route_detail` there is 1 `event`. This is child to `route_detail`

| id | route_detail_id | event_type | event_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | 1 | start visit |
| 51 | 2 | 2 | recurrent form |
| 52 | 3 | 3 | end visit |
| 53 | 4 | 1 | start visit |
| 54 | 5 | 1 | start visit |
| 55 | 6 | 1 | start visit |
| 56 | 7 | 2 | recurrent form |
| 57 | 8 | 1 | start visit |
| 58 | 9 | 2 | recurrent form |
| 59 | 10 | 4 | harvest advance |

What I'm trying to do is to get all the routes with `visit_status = 5` and that don't have events with `event_type = 3(end visit)`
But I can't manage to get that result

I tried something like this after some research but the queries would still return `routes` with `route_details` with the `event_type = 3` on them

```
SELECT r.id,
       r.start_day,
       r.end_day,
       de.point_of_delivery_plant_name,
       de.point_of_delivery_plant_number,
       de.visit_status
FROM route r
JOIN route_detail de ON de.route_id = r.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM route ro 
                  JOIN route_detail rd ON rd.route_id = ro.id 
                  JOIN event ev ON ev.route_detail_id = rd.id 
                  WHERE rd.route_id = r.id 
                    AND ev.event_type_id !=7 
                    AND rd.visit_status = '5' 
                    AND rd.id = de.id)
   AND de.visit_status = '5'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY r.id DESC;
```

This is how my results should look like, since only routes 4 and 5 have `visit_status = '5'` and their `route_details` don't have `event_type =3`

**Note**: I didn't make the tables

| id | start_day | end_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |
| 5 | 2023/05/01 | 2023/05/07 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with the `EXISTS` expression, you can use:

- one `EXISTS` to check the existence of `route_detail.visit_status = 5`
- one `EXISTS` to check the non-existence of `event.event_type = 3` when `route_detail.visit_status = 5`

```
SELECT r.*
FROM route r
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM route_detail rd
             WHERE r.id = rd.route_id
               AND rd.visit_status = 5 )
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM       route_detail rd
                 INNER JOIN "event"      e
                         ON rd.id = e.route_detail_id
                 WHERE r.id = rd.route_id
                   AND e.event_type = 3)
```

**Output**:

| id | start_day | end_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-05-07T00:00:00.000Z |
| 5 | 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-05-07T00:00:00.000Z |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uQpVtQuebKhiLPNuuwYLKj/0).

Comment: damn, you are awesome man, thanks. I didn't know you could use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` like that